# TFS 2017 git Branch Policy issue

Tags: git, tfs

Something strange was being happened with my branch policy for the master branch on the TFS 2017 recent time. It's configured to set only 1 reviewer for the pull request. However, after creation, there is two line of reviewers. One of them is in line to the policy, and a source of the second one is unknown.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xs2f9.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGhHp.png)

I don't know the command-line to retrieve the branch policies for TFS 2017, but from UI there is no other option to check.

What's a heck is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in order to close the question, I found the solution for this strange issue. I used the [TFS API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/previous-apis/policy/overview?view=tfs-2017) for branch policies and configuration and it turned out there are 2-3 the same configurations with filter settings that suites one branch twice at the time. I cannot see them by using UI.

Using the same TFS API but for deleting one of the policies, everything became normal.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you specified the `Minimum number of reviewers`, but not **maximum** number of reviewers. That means you can specify more than 1 reviewer.

From the second screenshot seems you have set the `Automatically include code reviewers` policy (*In your scenario you may added 2 users as automatic reviewers*), the automatic reviewers are required to approve the PRs. So if you have set that, then it's the expected behavior.

So, if you only want the user which you specified when create the pull request to approve the PR, then you can disable the `Automatically include code reviewers` policy.

[image]

Comment: Yes, the strange thing is that nothing else tells the system set 2 additional reviewers in this case. The automatic reviewers was the first thing that I checked. It's empty. And the behavior is happening only if something goes to the master by PR.